# Neo4j console : Type mismatch: expected Collection<T> but was Node

Tags: neo4j, console

I have a query that doesn't work. The error is:

> Type mismatch: expected Collection but was Node coming from FOREACH..

Code:

```
MATCH (user:User {user_role: 'Customer'})
WITH user
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[hv:HAS_VAUCHER]->(v:Vaucher {status: 2})
WITH user, count(hv) as hv
WHERE hv = 0
WITH user
FOREACH (u IN user | CREATE (v:Vaucher {discount: 5, created_at: 1488531600, start_at: 1488531600, type: 'March', status: 2})<-[:HAS_VAUCHER]-(u))
```

I don't know where the error is.

Answer (score 1):

While there are some improvements one could make to the query, here's a quick fix, dropping FOREACH since you don't have users in a collection, and you already have one user per row:

```
MATCH (user:User {user_role: 'Customer'})
WITH user
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[hv:HAS_VAUCHER]->(v:Vaucher {status: 2})
WITH user, count(hv) as hv
WHERE hv = 0
WITH user
CREATE (v:Vaucher {discount: 5, created_at: 1488531600, start_at: 1488531600, type: 'March', status: 2})<-[:HAS_VAUCHER]-(user)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but the point wasn't to create it only for one user.

Comment: It won't. `user` matches to all users with user_role 'Customer', so however many users match, that's how many :Vauchers will be created. The create operation executes per row, so all matched users will get their own :Vaucher

Answer (score 1):

I made a further research and the way to do it was to create a collection:

```
MATCH (user:User {user_role: 'Customer'})
WITH user
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[hv:HAS_VAUCHER]->(v:Vaucher {status: 2})
WITH user, count(hv) as hv
WHERE hv = 0
WITH user, COLLECT(user) AS users
FOREACH (u IN users | CREATE (v:Vaucher {discount: 5, created_at: 1488531600, start_at: 1488531600, type: 'March', status: 2})<-[:HAS_VAUCHER]-(u))
```

the "user" when returned returns N nodes (not 1) but when passed to FOREACH it maybe takes only the first node.

Comment: Both approaches work. FOREACH operates on collections, as you found out. But this is not necessary, as you already have all the users you need to work with on each row, so simply executing CREATE on user will do the exact same thing.

Comment: This answer solves the actual problem. The `user` objects need to be collected into a `list`. That's what the `COLLECT` is doing

Answer (score 1):

you can shorten the filtering part with a WHERE NOT clause and simplify query like this

```
MATCH (user:User {user_role: 'Customer'}) 
where not (user)-[:HAS_VAUCHER]->(:Vaucher {status: 2})
CREATE (v:Vaucher {discount: 5, created_at: 1488531600, 
start_at: 1488531600, type: 'March', status: 2})<-[:HAS_VAUCHER]-(u)
```